# how should data integrity be maintained in a situation where a foreign key relationship could be deleted

Tags: relational-database, data-integrity

Let's say I have a table of PlantGroups. They are dependent on the table Plants and have the foreign key PlantId. Each PlantGroup only contains one Plant.

```
PlantGroups
==========
...data...
PlantId

Plants
======
PlantId
```

If the record in the table Plants is deleted, or is requested to be deleted, what process should be taken to ensure the data integrity of PlantGroups?

Moreover, what if other data in the corresponding PlantGroups record (that was dependent on the Plants record which was requested for deletion) is still relevant and worth keeping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to go with `Option Other`. Although not defined in any Data Integrity guides I have read, including Oracles (who only lists NULL, CASCADE, RESTRICT, NO ACTION, DEFAULT as options), I am going to roll my own.

Here is what is going to happen unless someone else convinces me of a better approach.

```
PlantGroups
===========
... data  ...
PlantId

Plant
=====
PlantId
bool isActive
```

On delete of Plant isActive will be set to false. This will cause a lot of extra logic to be included in the management of the database but will allow for a shallow delete of these dependent fields. A cascade delete option will perhaps sit as a final option somewhere to deal with deprecated data which is over a certain amount of years old.

**Alternatively**

I could also have a second database which was the same schema as the first and held deleted data.

Answer (score 1):

Off the bat, if PlantGroups can have more than one Plant, you should have an extra table that has PlantGroupID and PlantID.

Depending on what you are trying to accomplish, you may want to have logic that will delete a PlantGroup if it has no Plants.  However, it would probably be easier to add logic that will ignore blank groups in some situations such as looking them up but show them when people need to add plants to a group.

For your other questions, you should look into cascading deletes.  Someone else might be able to provide more information on that.

Comment: editted question, each plantgroup can only contain one plant.

Comment: Adding logic is what I intend to do, but I am curious what others have to say. I am aware of cascade deletes, but as stated in the question, I would like to avoid that due to still relevant data.

Comment: You may want to keep information such as the most recent plant (or other information related to the plant) in the plant group, leaving the current plant to be something that can be deleted and later updated to a new plant.  Alternatively, you could keep a status with the plant to indicated that it was deleted so other logic can make more informed actions.  Such as not to display it in search results as active or to not allow the fields to be updated until it has a plant that is not deleted.  This all depends on if your system needs to allow these relationships to be more dynamic or static.

Comment: I like your comment and wrote a similar response just as you must have been typing that.